# Selenium XPath find element where second text child element contains certain text (use contains on array item)

Tags: selenium, xpath

The page contains a multi-select dropdown (similar to the one below)

[image: multi select dropdown]

The html code looks like the below:

```
<div class="button-and-dropdown-div>
<button class="Multi-Select-Button">multi-select button</button>
<div class="dropdown-containing-options>
    <label class="dropdown-item">
        <input class="checkbox">
        "  
                   Name
              "
    </label>
    <label class="dropdown-item">
        <input class="checkbox">
        "  
                   Address
              "
    </label>
</div>
```

After testing in firefox developer tools, I was finally able to figure out the xPath needed in order to get the text for a certain label ...

The below XPath statement will return the the text "Phone"

```
$x("(//label[@class='dropdown-item'])[4]/text()[2]")
```

The label contains multiple text items (although it looks like there is just one text object when looking at the UI) in the label element. There are actually two text elements within each label element. The first is always empty, the second contains the actual text (as shown in the below image when observing the element through the Firefox developer tool's console window):

[image]

**Question:**

How do I modify the XPath shown above in order to use in Selenium's FindElement?

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("?"));
```

I know how to use the contains tool, but apparently not with more complex XPath statements. I was pretty sure one of the below would work but they did not (develop tool complain of a syntax error):

```
$x("(//label[@class='dropdown-item' and text()[2][contains(., 'Name')]]")
$x("(//label[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(text()[2], 'Name')]")
```

I am using the 'contains' in order to avoid white-space conflicts.

---

**Additional for learning purposes** (good for XPath debugging):

just in case anyone comes across this who is new to XPath, I wanted to show what the data structure of these label objects looked like. You can explore the data structure of objects within your webpage by using the Firefox Console window within the developer tools (F12). As you can see, the label element contains three sub-items; text which is empty, then the inpput checkbox, then some more text which has the actual text in it (not ideal). In the picture below, you can see the part of the webpage that corresponds to the label data structure.

[image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find the element that contains "Name" given the HTML above, you can use

```
//label[@class='dropdown-item'][contains(.,'Name')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was actually the Label element which contained the text, not the input element. I spent too long just figuring that one out. It is not a normal data structure. I put some more information in the original question to help clarify why 'Name' is not part of the input for anyone new to XPath who comes across this page. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Yep... you are right. I simplified the XPath to target the `LABEL` element.

Comment: Nice. This works like a charm. This is actually better than what I put as an answer because (1) it is cleaner and easier to read and (2) it is less likely to break with code changes since it searches all elements within the label element for the text 'Name' instead of specifically looking within the second text child item for the text 'Name'. Really slick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. I learned a while back to separate the attribute searches instead of using `and`, etc. I think it makes them easier to read and maintain... but that's personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

So finally got it to work. The Firefox developer environment was correct when it stated there was a syntax problem with the XPath strings.

The following XPath string finally returned the desired result:

```
$x("//label[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(text()[2], 'Name')]")
```

Comment: FYI, you don't want to use the index `[2]` because you are already finding the element by "Name". If that element ever moves in the DOM, your locator won't find it. See my answer for the XPath.